# Issue in creating a search engine using nutch 0.9

Tags: apache, tomcat, search-engine, nutch

I have followed the steps from  [here](http://zillionics.com/resources/articles/NutchGuideForDummies.htm)

For the step 3(e), below is my conf/nutch-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>searcher.dir</name>
    <value>C:\nutch-0.9\crawl\</value>
</property>
```

[Here, I think there is some issue, which I am not able to identify. And i don't know what else to put here as I am not familiar with xml tags]

Also, the above file is same as my C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\nutch-0.9\WEB-INF\classes\nutch-site.xml
[which is Step 4(d) ]

After completing all the instructions in the tutorial, and entering the url http://localhost:8080
It simply shows the normal apache tomcat homepage, and not the one shown in the tutorial [Nutch search page, step 4(e))]

Software / tools used:

Nutch 0.9, apache tomcat 8.5, windows 10.

Please help in solving the above issue. Thanks.

{ EDit: My requirement is that, I have to use Nutch 0.9 for this task. ]

Comment: Nutch 0.9 is no longer maintained. A lot of changes have been introduced after that version.

Answer (score 1):

Nutch 0.9 was released in May 2007, more than eleven years ago. You need to use it with a software stack of the same time - the [Nutch guide](http://zillionics.com/resources/articles/NutchGuideForDummies.htm) you've mentioned runs Nutch 0.9 on Java 6 and Tomcat 6.

Upgrading the software to run on recent versions of Java and Tomcat could be a lot of work.